# Round Corners in custom UICollectionViewCell not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

I have custom UICollectionViewCell and try to round corners for button, which doesn't work.
I had the same problem for ViewController and the problem was that I was doing rounding in viewDidLoad instead of subviewsDidLoad.

I had no idea what is a problem now.

sharing my code.

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        initialsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * initialsButton.frame.size.width
        initialsButton.clipsToBounds = true
        initialsButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

-> but I also tried without .clipsToBounds and .masksToBounds. Same result.

Here is the result. [It is not a circle, it makes corner wrongly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbxOY.png)
[SEE THIS RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cb2x.png)

Comment: For applying rounded corners to any view, you just need to give cornerRadius and make clipsToBounds = true. That's it.

Comment: @DharaPatel https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cb2x.png see this result. I did cornerRadius and clipsToBounds. My code is here. What is the problem why I have thi result?

Comment: Please make sure your button has equal height and width, if you want to make round button.

Comment: Yes, its ratio is 1:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing rounding corners in awakeFromNib(), instead you MUST do it in layoutSubviews() and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using IBOutlet's
Create a class something like this, add button to your cell in storyboard, edit there how ever you want, it easier. Your code up is not good, just remove size, frame.height / 2 is what you want if you are going that way.

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedBtn: UIButton {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: Double {
    get {
        return Double(self.layer.cornerRadius)
    }set {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: Double {
    get {
        return Double(self.layer.borderWidth)
    }
    set {
        self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(newValue)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: self.layer.borderColor!)
    }
    set {
        self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: self.layer.shadowColor!)
    }
    set {
        self.layer.shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOffSet: CGSize {
    get {
        return self.layer.shadowOffset
    }
    set {
        self.layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowRadius: Double {
    get {
        return Double(self.layer.shadowRadius)
    }set {
        self.layer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(newValue)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return self.layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    self.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow + 1, for: .vertical)
    self.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow + 1, for: .horizontal)
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let size = self.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize
    return CGSize(width: size.width + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right, height: size.height + contentEdgeInsets.top + contentEdgeInsets.bottom)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel!.frame.size.width
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for sharing but the whole idea was that I wanted a circle button, so I must use width/2 and it can't be done using some constant pxs. But I created RoundButton class and not it works.